# Python: Printing a list without the brackets and single quotes?

Tags: python, list, printing, loops

I have a list full of IP addresses.  I would like to iterate through the list and print each IP address.  When I try doing this:

```
def printList(theList):
    for item in theList:
        print item
```

And the output looks like this:

```
['8.0.226.5']
['8.0.247.5']
['8.0.247.71']
['8.0.249.28']
['8.0.249.29']
```

I have tried everything, including "print item[0]" in the loop.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Really? What happened when you tried `print item[0]`?

Comment: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Could you show us what this list looks like?

Comment: That error can only occur if a list is empty. The lists you printed are all non-empty.

Comment: Doing repr(item) does the same thing.  Delnan, the list isn't empty, but apparently it thinks the "item" in the loop isn't a list. (Even though it sure is printing like one).

Comment: @Dan: One list you're trying to take the item with index 0 from must be empty. I see that what you printed is not empty, but index 0 is only out of range when there isn't a (0+1)th item, i.e. when the list is empty, so if you get that error there must be an empty list, period. Show the code and exampel data (`print repr(theList)` should give you an exact representation of the list) that causes the error (e.g. on http://www.pastebin.com).

Comment: Think you could take a look? http://pastebin.com/as1mt09s

Answer (score 6):

Each item in the list is itself a singleton list. There's propably no reason for this - if you can't name one, go and remove them (by using `re.find` over `re.findall` or returning a single item from the list returned by `re.findall`), they're just redundant and cause trouble like in this case.

Regardless, `print item[0]` should work as it's printing the single element in the list, and unlike the `str()` of lists, it won't run the item through `repr` first (which causes the quotes and would escape unprintable characters if there were any in the string). And once you got rid of the redundant singleton lists, `print '\n'.join(items)` will work as well.

Your code throws an error if there is an empty list in `theList`. If there is a line in `recentFile` that does not contain anything formatted like an IP, an empty list will be returned by `returnIP`, and if any line in `comparisonFile` (by the way: you open it with a descriptive name at the beginning, but open it again and again without a descriptive name in `chechMatch`) contains no IP address either, you'll get another empty list which of course equals the empty list passed as parameter `ip`. So for non-IP names in `recentFile`, empty lists will be added. This whole troubel can be avoided if you return strings instead of singleton lists from `returnIP`, use `None` when there is no IP in the current line, and skip the checking/appending in `compareFiles` if `returnIP` returns `None`.

Comment: I figured it out.  Apparently at the top of the list had a blank item, so it was stopping there.  Thanks for your help!  Edit: I'm not a member, or I'd upvote you :(

Comment: @Dan: Added detailed explanation why it happens and suggestions how to resolve it. A bit late, but if any of it helps... :)

Comment: Thanks!  For the comparisonFile thing, I was originally referencing it later on but for some reason it wouldn't work when using the variable name so I tried replacing it with the open function inline and it worked fine.  I'm not sure why this happened.  I might try to recreate the problem and try to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I think *theList* is not a list of IPs but a list of lists of IPs(each of them with 1 element).

Another cause of the problem would be that you have an IP class with an overwritten **str** method that prints it like that.